# Mail labeled Inbox, not showing in inbox

Tags: gmail

I have a user whose email before yesterday has vanished from their inbox.  Looking at ALL mail and sent mail, which shows some items labeled INBOX that don't show in the Inbox. Other than marking said messages - unread (which is not the case) I'm not sure why they don't show in the Inbox.

Checking my own account - messages I reply to show up both in my sent mail and in my inbox.

Messages this user replies to only show up in the sent mail container.

However, this user also checks their email by phone - so I wonder if that is where the problem lies?  I would appreciate other's thoughts on this.

Comment: Do they use the category tabs? Messages labelled "inbox" may not be under the Primary tab.

Comment: They have a handful - Social, Promotions, Updates, Forums - the oddity seems to be that mail replied to threads go to the sent folder, show the Inbox label but don't appear in the inbox.  Also, it appears to be like some sort of setting that says anything older than say 48 hours, don't show.  So while I know it is in theory in the inbox, I'm not sure how to make it show.

Comment: So they're just using the "normal" inbox? No Gmail labs? No Priority Inbox? Try turning off all of the categories (except Primary, which you can't turn off) and see if the messages will appear then.

Comment: Normal inbox.  Only Lab is a calendar one.  No Priority Inbox.  Turned off all categories - closed mail and browser, reopened - still no messages prior to 10/17 showing.

Answer (score 4):

Just fixed the issue for me!  I was looking within the Inbox in the Primary category, the other categories are listed across the top (Forums, Updates, Promotions).  My missing email was in Updates.   Under Settings -> Inbox turn off all the Options under Primary (I could turn off Primary as well) and save.  All my email in the Inbox showed up in the one list. Turn on the ones you want, but I deselected Updates as it was picking up important email that wasn't an "update".

Answer (score 0):

I just solved a problem with the same symptoms.  In Gmail (G Suite), Inbox showed no mails at all, but "All Mail" showed many messages labelled "Inbox".  New mails would arrive, and on the left they would show in the unread message count, "Inbox (2)", but when switching to Inbox no messages would be shown.

I resolved the issue by going to "Settings" -> "Inbox", then changing the "Inbox type" to "Priority" and saving the settings.   Messages were showing in the Inbox again, and when I changed "Inbox type" back to "Default" they were still showing.

The issue possibly arose because I had been making a lot of changes to the settings including changing a lot of labels.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, still happening.  Sent myself some test emails from another site.
Emails not in the inbox, but are in the 'all mail' box.
The settings adjustment of the inbox type described above, did NOT solve the issue.

Gmail has a serious flaw, where mail that you get, does NOT show in the inbox.

My guess, its a heuristic filter that is just filtering them out (I have zero filters I created, so its not self inflicted).

Incoming mail ends up not in Spam or any other group other than 'All Mail'.  How the heck are we supposed to trust Gmail as  mail tool?

Comment: I'd say that the first paragraph would probably be a good comment on the other answer.  As is, this is not really an answer on its own.